# Re-Installation Of Ubuntu

Tags: installation

My system was running fine on 10.10 and upgraded to 12.04 it was extremely slow (may be because of less hard disk or RAM)so I decided to go back to 9.04 as i had a bootable cd for that and when they ask for partition I agreed to use my whole hard disk as a file system without any partition and now that 9.04 is not running properly and every time the Grub is coming up I am not even able to have a flash player even

So could you please advice how can I make partition as I am not able to use Gparted from 9.04 and then how to re-install Windows 7 and format all other drives along with installed Ubuntu 9.04 and delete all Grubs and stuff and then after installing Windows 7 properly I would Like again re-install 10.10.

Or if you guys have any other way for that please advice me on that but remember I want remove all the other grub stuff and start it from fresh. I also dont mind to have just ubuntu on my system.

Please any one can provide step by step procedure for that.

Comment: If you still have a 10.10 LiveCD you can use gparted from there and then use the 9.04 CD for installation. Otherwise use fdisk from terminal.

Comment: thanks, but can you please be precise or step by step information as i just mere a beginner

Comment: Step by step tutorials on how to use Gparted, install W7, formatting partitions and reinstalling Ubuntu, all in one question? It would take a thick book to cover all those topics.

Comment: @mikewhatever C'mon dude, I'll throw a 50-point bounty if you hit 20,000 words in your answer. Should only take a week or so...

Comment: okay I will write you down step by step ....mike and let you know how many words it would take.

As I already used Fdisk for partion as Gparted was not working and installed W7 already just one thing is missing is Ubuntu re-installation as it would not boot up through Cd dont know why but figure I will figure it out

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

So what you have to do:

- Run Ubuntu from LiveCD (make sure in the BIOS boot order, the CD drive comes before the hard drive)
- If your LiveCD doesn't come with Gparted preinstalled, try to install it by entering `sudo apt-get install gparted` into a terminal. If that fails, use `fdisk`. Here are tutuorials:
- With what ever tool runs from your LiveCD, partition your hard drive to have a Linux ext3/4 partition, a windows ntfs partition and a linux swap partition. Here is a tutorial for [Gparted](http://dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html) and [fdisk](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html)
- Shutdown, insert Windows 7 install DVD and  install Windows 7 with it (make sure Windows 7 uses the NTFS partition and does not override the others)
- Install Ubuntu from LiveCD and this time make sure (in the extended install options) that the mountpoint for `/` is your Linux partition.
- You're done. Grub shuld automatically reinstall with Ubuntu and recognize Windows 7.

On more details she die [Installation Guide for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation).

Comment: Thanks a lot ...but now the issue is:

I was able to install Windows 7 and it is running fine but you know it is no fun at all I need ubuntu but I am tried to install ubuntu 12.04 and as well as 10.10 with a CD it is not working, I tried everything but with CD it was not working (I did not tried with USB), I have 3 partitions 
1. Windows partition Primary NTFS
2. Empty Primary Partition NTFS
3. Logical Partition which I made it through Disk Management and Shrink the Volume.
But any how I am not able to boot up the CD and install Ubuntu.